# Angular 5 - reactive form- is there a way to patch value using a variable?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form group with many fields :

```
    this.addressForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        line1: ['', Validators.required],
        line2: '',
        line3: '',
        line4: '',
        line5: '',
        line6: '',
        line7: '',
        line8: '',
    });
```

In my html I have a form field to each formControl and a button near it that clears that form control.

```
                <mat-form-field>
                    <mat-label>line 1</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="line1" type="text">
                    <button type="button" (click)="clearLine('line1')">
                    </button>
                </mat-form-field>
```

How Can I write a *generic* methods that gets the name of the form control and clears it?

I tries this-

```
clearLine(line) {
    this.addressForm.patchValue({line: ''});
}
```

but that did not work, because it searched for a formControl name "line".

Is there any way to do this without execute many "if" conditions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try this

```
clearLine(line) {
    this.addressForm.patchValue({[line]: ''}); // added []
}
```

Comment: no prob!... adding brackets will make the access substitute variables names. Just like object['hey'] equals object.hey.
Happy coding!